# How can I write to file without using the redirection operator?

Tags: bash

How can I write the output from `ls`, `cat`, or some other command to file without typing `>` at some point? A similar question was asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/write-to-a-file-without-redirection). However, that asker did not want to use **ANY** shell syntax, whereas I am happy to use most shell features, just not the redirection operators (pipe is okay, just not `<` or `>`). Also, it would be nice to not use `sudo` or any other permission granting command. I am just writing to something in my home directory; I already have write permissions.

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid a perfectly good, basic shell construct?

Comment: The preponderance would suggest that it is either a challenge or homework question designed to have the user investigate `tee`.

Comment: Write a program in another language which does not use `>`, for example `tee` is probably written in C (but awk and Perl both use `>`).  But then, why are you using `bash` in the first place if you don't want to use `bash` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `tee`:

```
echo this is a test | tee -a somefile.txt
```

Or `dd`:

```
echo this is a test | dd of=somefile.txt
```

There are probably a variety of other similar solutions.